# FOS UserBundle and Twig Error

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

recently I've been trying to install `FOSUserBundle` with my `Symfony 2.1` application. I went through the installation and configuration process with no errors. However, when I typed `myapp/app_dev.php/login` path into browser address bar, I got a following error:

```
ErrorException: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /home/kasia/WWW/herold-statistik/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/NodeVisitor/Scope.php line 94
```

This error seems to appear on every subpage that uses `FOS templates`. It only disappears when `{% extends %}` and `{% block %}` tags are removed from `Twig` files. Overriding templates didn't work for me.

I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not from the **FOSUserBundle**. It's from a fix of the **TwigBridge**. There is a pending PR but you can fix it manually look [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/7281).

Comment: what am i supposed to do with that?

Comment: you can see the exact changes [here](https://github.com/jfsimon/symfony/commit/fe4cc249b500323b9bde6acff04182a86414c88f#L0R37)

Comment: yeah, i did that 2 days ago, tnx